# Error 1064 importing data from Excel, reserved character

Tags: mysql, excel, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to import a table from Excel 2010 into MySQL 5.6 via MySQL for Excel.

It errors out giving me a `MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...`

The actual character causing the error is a semicolon inside the data field being imported.  When I replaced all of the ";" with `&#59#` (but **not** `&#59;`) it worked fine.

How do I import these files without changing the data?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution using MySQL for Excel, but as an alternative to replacing the semicolons, you can save the Excel sheet as a CSV file and use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html). Here's an example of the syntax you might use from a Windows machine with a remote connection to the database server:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/path/to/my_excel_data.csv'
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

MySQL will correctly interpret a Windows path with forward slashes in a `LOAD DATA` statement.

Note that the `LOCAL` keyword signals for the MySQL client to read the file, so in this case "local" means with respect to the client software, NOT with respect to the database server.

This may also behave a bit oddly if you have unmatched `"` characters in any of the cells in your spreadsheet. For instance, if the cell contains `here is " an unmatched double-quote`, Excel will both enclose the string in double-quotes and double the unmatched double-quote in the string when saving as CSV, so what you get is `"here is "" an unmatched double-quote"`. I'm not sure how MySQL will react in this situation.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but, as you say, it gave problems with unmatched double-quotes, single-quotes, and every other delimiter I used.